# The C# app hangs up when reading from and writing to a NamedPipeServerStream *from the same thread*

Tags: c#, .net, windows, deadlock, named-pipes

For the past month or so I've been debugging an apparent deadlock caused by a thread reading from and writing to a NamedPipeServerStream, like this:

```cs
NamedPipeServerStream pipestream = new NamedPipeServerStream(@"\\.\foo.bar", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
//Wait for client connection here
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
while (true)
{
  int n = await pipestream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, n);
  if (n > 0)
  {
    await pipestream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, n);
    await pipestream.FlushAsync();
  }
  else
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

This code is part of a WPF app, and when the "deadlock" happens, the entire app including the GUI freezes as if the message loop itself is somehow stopped.

Before the deadlock happens, the app works for some arbitrary amount of time (including the echoback loop) so the implementation seems to be correct except for the deadlock.

(The app runs on x86-64 Windows)

I tried many workarounds including making the calls to Read() and Write() synchronous, calling WaitForPipeDrain(), changing the PipeTransmissionMode to PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, removing the Asynchronous flag, changing the buffer size, not flushing after writing, checking for CanWrite and CanRead results, waiting until IsMessageComplete etc. but they didn't work at all.

What did work in the end was running two threads, one for reading and the other for writing, and echoing the data through a System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe instance, like this (I don't believe the fact that I used System.IO.Pipelines specifically is relevant for the fix though):

Main thread:

```cs
System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe pipe = new Pipe();
NamedPipeServerStream pipestream = new NamedPipeServerStream(@"\\.\foo.bar", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
//Wait for client connection here
//Start thread 1 and 2
```

Thread 1:

```cs
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
while (true)
{
  int n = await pipestream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 4096);
  if (n > 0)
  {
    await pipe.Writer.AsStream().WriteAsync(buffer);
    await pipe.Writer.AsStream().FlushAsync();
  }
  else
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

Thread 2:

```cs
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
while (true)
{
  int n = await pipe.Reader.AsStream().ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 4096);
  if (n > 0)
  {
    await pipestream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, n);
    await pipestream.FlushAsync();
  }
  else
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

I did some stress tests on this implementation and the deadlock seems to be gone forever which is bizarre to me. What I just did was basically writing the exact same thing but separated into two threads. The only possible explanation that I could come up with is that the Named Pipe implementation on Windows uses some thread-local data structures, but I can't think of any reasonable reason why.

Does anyone have an idea how this happens? Is it simply that I'm using Named Pipes wrong?

I would be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You lost the battle with the security software installed on this machine.  Short from raising its hackles by having an .exe file appearing from seemingly no-where and quickly getting launched, the pipe tends to be enough to convince it that this may be malware.  Until it probed it several times and leaves you in peace.  Easy to fix, do consider that you'll need a sound installer to deploy this app.

Comment: I assume you have two pipes, one in each direction.  I suspect you are having a flush issue.  You have a master/slave interface where one side sends commands and the other receives.  You will get a dead lock when one side doesn't receive entire message before returning response.

Comment: In bidirectional communication, it's normal to have to have a read going all the time, even while writing. You don't need two threads; you can do this with two asynchronous methods running concurrently.